# How to change CSS class of <a> tag using Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to change the class of a tab on the dashboard depending upon the page selected.
I have 3 tabs in the dashboard like

```
<div>
    <ul class="menu">
    <li class="MenuDashboard"><a href="#" >Dashboard</a></li>
    <li class="MenuSearch"><a href="#">Search</a></li>
    <li class="MenuAccountSetup"><a href="#">Account Set up</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now I want to highlight the tab when I select that particular tab. By default the 'Dashboard' tab should be highlighted. I have a style class called "current" which highlights the tab.
Please advise.

Comment: If you already have a class called "current" that highlights the tab, where's the issue?

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
$('.menu li').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
});

// Clicks on the first menu item to style it
$('.menu li').eq(0).click();
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the class to the default tab: `<li class="MenuDashboard active"><a href="#" >Dashboard</a></li>`

Comment: They can also just use the class `current` and replace all instances of `active` in this example.