# Can I highlight an active menu item by using id="current" on a single page with ancored objects?

Tags: html, css, menuitem, highlighting

I'm working on this site: http://fridasofia.se/dw/index.php
which is a single page, and the navigation is linked to anchored objects.

Is it possible to highlight the active menu item by using id="current" ?

I have used this in pages where every menu item leds to different pages, but now the whole site is on one single page, so I don't know if this is posible?

Is there any other way to do this?

The code for the site: http://pastebin.com/3UrLvkgF

Thanks!

Comment: Similar question was asked recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399174/how-to-change-css-class-of-a-tag-using-jquery-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `:active` selector:

```
a:active {
  background: url(img/pil.png);
}
```

Comment: But the active selector only styles the link when I click on it, i. e. when I press the mouse button down, then the styles "disappear again when i release the button.

Comment: In that case you'll need a JavaScript solution. See @Aaron's link for my answer to *that* question.